# Parametrized full text search query

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a full text search query and try add to it Sql parameters.
Here is my code

```
using (var connection = GetDbConnection())
         {
            connection.Open();
            using (var cmd =
               new SqlCommand(
                  string.Format("ALTER FULLTEXT STOPLIST [{0}] ADD @stopWord LANGUAGE [{1}];", stopWord.StopList,
                     stopWord.Language), (SqlConnection)connection))
            {
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stopWord", stopWord.StopWord);

               cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
         }
```

But it thows an error

> Incorrect syntax near '@stoplist'. --->
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near '@stoplist'.

How can I construct my query to protect from sql injections?
For example as stopWord value I can send this with quote symbol

> test's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape the single quote

```
stopWord.StopWord = stopWord.StopWord.Replace("'", "''")
```

Comment: How to deal with other characters?

Comment: @user2455111 can you specify what other characters